# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL database on Amazon RDS from pgAdmin4: internal server error: port 5432 failed: timeout expired

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, timeout, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I'm getting this error while performing the steps from the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDMgXZUfa10&t=897s

The error:

[image]

Comment: Tons of possibilities here - is public access enabled? username password are correct? port correct? etc. we need exact info.

Comment: Is it publicly accessible? Did you configure the SG properly?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary port, username and pw are correct, but i'm not sure where exactly check public access. Can you please provide the info? I know that this database is used by others members of the team and they have no problems while conecting.

Comment: Connecting with the same UI? Are you on a VPN? There's so many factors at play here; it would be best to consult team members if they can connect to assist you.

Answer (score 3):

try to configure security group.
EC2 -> Security Groups -> choose your security group -> edit -> check source
(0.0.0.0/0 allows everyone to connect to the database)